# Deploying a next.js application, via the serverless framework, within an azure devops pipeline(YAML)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, next.js, serverless-framework

I've created a next.js application and have installed the serverless framework so that I can deploy the application.

I can do this via cli with either a .env file containing the AWS credentials or with no .env file but with my AWS credentials sitting in the .aws folder locally. However I can't have the AWS credentials sitting in the root folder permanently as this poses security risks.

What I need to achieve now is for the application to be deployed as part of an Azure devops pipeline(YAML).

The challenge I'm facing is passing the AWS credentials to the serverless deployment without making it part of version control.

This is the current state of my yaml pipeline.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npx next build
    npx serverless
  displayName: 'npm install, build and deploy'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The challenge I'm facing is passing the AWS credentials to the serverless deployment without making it part of version control.

You could try to upload the credentials to Azure Devops as [Secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops). Then you could directly use the [Download secure file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to download the credentials.

In this case , the secure files will not be a part of Repo.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Upload the credentials to **Pipelines-> Library -> Secure files.**

[image: Secure files]

Step2: Add the `Download secure file` task to the Yaml definition.

For example:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'file name'
```

Note: the secure file will be downloaded to `$(Agent.TempDirectory)`. When the build is complete, this file will be automatically deleted.

In addition， if you want to keep this file or put it elsewhere, you can add a `Copy file task`.

For example:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Hope this helps.